# Adding disqus to a meteor.js project

Tags: javascript, meteor, disqus

i am trying to add the disqus commentsystem to my application.
I followed the instruction written in this article [KLICK](http://louisrli.github.io/blog/2013/07/29/using-meteor-js-with-disqus/#.Up4y8sQ2aSU)

I created a template called disqus.html

```
 <template name="disqus">
  {{#isolate}}
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>  
  {{/isolate}}
 </template>
```

If this template is rendered, embed.js should load once and disqus makes a reset.

```
Template.disqus.rendered = function() {  
  Session.set("loadDisqus", true);

  return typeof DISQUS !== "undefined" && DISQUS !== null ? DISQUS.reset({
    reload: true,
    config: function() {}
  }) : void 0;
};
```

React on sessionchange in deps.autorun

```
Meteor.startup (function () {
  Deps.autorun(function() {
    if(Session.get("loadDisqus") && !window.DISQUS) {
      var disqus_shortname = '<example>'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

    (function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();      

    }
  });
});
```

This works fine in Firefox 25.0.1. I can login, logout and create comments. But it isnt working in Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m. It is not possible for me to login. No error is thrown.
What can i do? Any suggestions?

Even a login to disqus in [discovermeteor.com/...](http://www.discovermeteor.com/2013/09/17/meteor-for-front-end-engineers/) is not possible for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using session here is interesting but unnecessary.
Here is what i migth do in your disqus.js file:

```
var isDisqusLoaded = false,
  myScriptLoader = function funcMyScriptLoader(jsEl, callback) {
    if (window.attachEvent) {
      // for IE (sometimes it doesn't send loaded event but only complete)
      jsEl.onreadystatechange = function funcOnReadyStateChange() {
        if (jsEl.readyState === 'complete') {
          jsEl.onreadystatechange = "";
        } else if (jsEl.readyState === 'loaded') {
          jsEl.onreadystatechange = "";
        }

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback();
        }
      };
    } else {
      // most browsers
      jsEl.onload = function funcOnLoad () {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback();
        }
      };
    }
  };

Template.disqus.rendered = function funcTplDisqusRendered() {
  if (!isDisqusLoaded) {
    var myElJs = document.createElement('script'),
      s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    myElJs.type = 'text/javascript';
    myElJs.async = true;
    myElJs.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';

    myScriptLoader(myElJs, function funcEventLoaded() {
      isDisqusLoaded = true;
    });

    s.parentNode.insertBefore(myElJs, s);
  }
};
```

Using that script you won't need to use Deps.autorun and Session.
You should use that kind of feature only where you want to get realtime, but if don't need it, avoid it coz it will degrade your app performance.

You can add Disqus.reset if it's really needed but i'm not sure, look at the disqus documentation.

I didn't test the script but it should be ok.

Comment: Nice idea to avoid Deps.autorun. Do you have any information how much performance is lost using to muchs autoruns? Maybe there are some statistics. I will give it a try and test it, but first could you explain me the functioncall of myScriptLoader? I cant get it. Whats M6.Events.manager?

Comment: No information about it because. But it depends a lot on client's hardware. It might be heavy on smartphone/tablet but useless to think about it on coreI7 desktop. I removed Events.manager coz it's useless here. myScriptLoader will take your script dom element and add an event listener using onload/onreadystatechange (depending on browser) and then this listener will run the callback when the event is triggered.

Comment: I was checking every line of your code. The callback myCallback in myScriptloader is not called. I would omit this function definiton. Why not just write something like:myScriptLoader(myElJs, function funcEventLoaded() {
        isDisqusLoaded = true;
    });

Comment: yep that's right i did a mistake, i edited the sample. It should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a weird cacheing error, have you tried resetting chrome's cache?

Comment: It was not a cashing problem. I my chrome were third-party-cookies deactivated. So diqus couldnt create a cookie and was not able to save the login. Maybe this should be mentioned in the diqus docs.